# Slow Down Button Animation Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am using animation for my button but its too fast when I click the animation happens so fast you can barely see at the moment its just two drawables with a selector.xml state pressed true

How can I so slow the animation just a little bit

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:enterFadeDuration` and `android:exitFadeDuration`to achieve your desired effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="400" android:exitFadeDuration="400">
    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

This `android:duration="200"`  is the time in miliseconds that your animation will occur. Go for 500 (0,5 seconds) or more if you want.